# codeigniter how to get the value of table row

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just wondering if you could help me get the value of a table row, then placing it to a model.

**Here is my view:**

```
<div class="table_design">
        <style>
            #tbl_ulist1 tr:hover td{
                background-color: yellow;
            }  

            #txt_fn1{
                border: none;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

        </style>
        <form action="userslist" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" id="new_user" name="new_user" value="Add New User"/>
            <table id="tbl_ulist1">
                <tr>
<!--                    <th>Edit/Delete</th>-->
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                    <th>Birth Date</th>
                    <th>Contact Details</th>
                    <th>Email Add</th>
                    <th>User Type</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($userslist as $row) { ?>
                <tr id="tr1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

                    <!--<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/edit_user'); ?>/<?php echo $row->ID ?>">Edit</a></td>-->
                    <td><input type="text" id="txt_fn1" value="<?php echo $row->FirstName ?>" readonly/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->LastName ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->MiddleName ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Birthdate ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->ContactDetails ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->EmailAdd ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->UserType ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Status ?></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and here is my div modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 80%; height: 60%; margin-top: 200px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                 <h4 style="color: black;"></h4>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 60%; border: none;" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/edit_user'); ?>"></iframe>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the view of my iframe in my modal:

```
<div id="content">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
<style>

    #tbl_edituser{
        color: black;
    }

</style>

<form action="edit_user" method="POST" name="frm_edituser" id="frm_edituser">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit User</legend>
        <table id="tbl_edituser">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_userfirst" id="txt_userfirst" value="<?php //echo $system_users->FirstName ?>"/></td>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_userlast" id="txt_userlast" value="<?php //echo $system_users->LastName ?>"/></td>
                <td>Middle Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_usermiddle" id="txt_usermiddle" value="<?php //echo $system_users->MiddleName ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="txt_edituserID" id="txt_edituserID" value="<?php //echo $system_users->ID ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Birth Date:</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="dt_user" id="dt_user" style="width: 100%; height: 80%" value="<?php //echo //$system_users->Birthdate ?>"/></td>
                <td>Email Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_emailaddress" id="txt_emailaddress" value="<?php// echo $system_users->EmailAdd ?>"/></td>
                <td>Contact Details:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_contactdetails" id="txt_contactdetails" value="<?php// echo $system_users->ContactDetails ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_editusername" id="txt_editusername" value="<?php// echo $system_users->Username ?>"/></td>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="txt_editpassword" id="txt_editpassword" value="<?php //echo $system_users->Password ?>"/></td>
                <td>User Type:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="cbo_editusertype" name="cbo_editusertype" style="width: 100%">
                        <option><?php// echo $system_users->UserType ?></option>
                        <option>Administrator</option>
                        <option>User</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="cbo_edituserstatus" name="cbo_edituserstatus" style="width: 100%">
                        <option><?php //echo $system_users->Status ?></option>
                        <option>Active</option>
                        <option>Inactive</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btn_edituserdetails" name="btn_edituserdetails" onclick="validate_editsystemusers();" value="Update"/>&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btn_deleteuserdetails" name="btn_deleteuserdetails" onclick="validate_deletesystemuser();" value="Delete"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="ninja14" id="ninja14" value=""/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the controller of my modal:

```
public function edit_user(){
//   $data_users['system_users'] = $this->inventory_model->select_systemusers();
//   $this->load->view('homeview');
     $this->load->view('edituser_view');
//   $this->load->view('footer_view');
}
```

Help me on this one please! I've spend hours thinking about this one.

Comment: I assume you want to be able to click on a row and have that row appear in the model?

Comment: I just want the values on the row appear in the modal, i changed my source in my frame to: src="<?php echo site_url('inventorysys_controller/edit_user'); ?>/<?php echo $row->ID ?>"

Comment: I am able to get the values of the last row always, even when i click the first row.

Comment: For something like this I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do it without using javascript.

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, what i'm trying to figure out is how can I use javascript to get those values.

Comment: Do you want it to be displayed in the modal as a table?

Comment: I just solved it man, i put a href on the <tr>. Damn, been thinking about this for days. Hahaha! Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: Instead of using iframe, you can use load data remotely in modal. Check out remote method of bootstrap modal for more help